# Combobox User manual input and Selection change

Tags: wpf, forms, events, combobox

I am trying to raise two different action which will expose additional field when ever there is a selection change on the Combobox and Manual Text input.
However, one triggers the other.

```
SelectionChanged="ComboBoxAccount_SelectionChanged"
TextBoxBase.TextChanged="ComboBoxAccount_textChanged"
```

How could I exactly determine there was a user manual input and not selection change which being population by different selections on the form and by doing that raise two different events?

Answer (score 0):

I have used on the ComboBoxAccount_SelectionChanged() the  comboxAccount.IsKeyboardFocusWithin check to determine if it is manual input or not.

```
 private void ComboBoxAccount_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {   
    if (this.comboxAccount.IsDropDownOpen && comboxAccount.comboxAccount.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
    {.....}
    else if (comboxAccount.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
                {....}
    }
```